# Parameters in a Neural Network Model

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, logistic-regression

Is it possible to establish a classification model explained by parameters using neural networks, as in a logit or in a linear probability model?

Comment: A (softmax-ended) NN defines P(y|x). In what way is that insufficient?

Comment: in a logit model we see logit(y)=bo+b1x1+....+error term, is it possible to establish these parameters for p(y given x) by using a NN?

Comment: See my answer on how it is not possible, if unclear, let's continue there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The neural network IS a classification model explained by its parameters.

Let's go back to the basics. Consider a single neuron with N inputs and an output. It applies a function of the form:

x = g(weighted sum of all inputs)

, where g is some nonlinear function, such as sigmoid or tanh or ReLU - the exact function does impact the performance, but is not relevant to our discussion.

The problem is that the *separation surface* between the classes is linear (assuming a classification based on something like x>0.5).

The problem is that many real-world problems are not linear. They are actually extremely complex problems, so we need a model that can estimate such highly nonlinear functions.

Now, let's imagine a small neural network, with 2 neurons on the first layer and 1 neuron on the output layer.

The 2 neurons on the input layer will have their outputs:

x_1 = g(weighted sum of all inputs)
x_2 = g(weighted sum of all inputs)

(g is usually the same for all neurons on one layer. It doesn't *have* to be, but it doesn't make much sense otherwise. For the rest of the discussion, let's assume g is the same everywhere).

Now, x_1 and x_2 are inputs for the neuron on the other layer, thus its output (and the output of the whole network) is:

X = w_1*x_1 + w_2*x_2 = w_1*g(weighted sum of all inputs) + w_2*g(weighted sum of all inputs)

That is the *function* estimated by a neural network with N inputs, 2 neurons on the input layer and one neuron on the output layer. It is, of course, parametrized by 2n+2 weights: n weights for each input neuron and 2 weights for the output neuron.

As you can notice, this expression is quite hard to write on paper (even harder to write on StackOverflow), and it will get *extremely* complicated for deep neural networks. However, in essence, all neural networks are a simple graphical model of this long, but relatively simple expression, where we do a weighted sum of the inputs of each node and apply a nonlinear function.

The trend towards deep neural network rises due to the ability of such model to estimate highly nonlinear functions. Technically, by the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem), we need only one hidden layer (think of the previous network with 2 neurons on the input layer, with much more than 2 neurons on that layer). But that turns out to be quite unpractical to design an train (partially due to high number of neurons required on that layer). So people started stacking more and more layers on top of another, and we got the complex architectures we have nowdays: large chains of additions, multiplications and g's.

Answer (score 0):

Building on your comment, in a logit model, you have `logit = b_0 + b_1*x_1 + ... b_k*x_k + e = b_0 + w^T.x + e`, and then `P(y=1|x) = \sigma(logit)`.

What a classification neural network does, is that it replaces the linear (affine) `b_0 + w^T.x` by a complex nonlinear function `NN(x)`. So while you can easily retrieve its parameters `w`, the actual `logit = f_w(x)` will be as ugly as your 152 layers deep ResNet dictates.

Another interpretation is that all layers of an NN simply extract some better feature of your data and the last layer is your ordinary logit model (or multiclass logistic regression or whatever). Unfortunately, while you the classifier is now familiar, it operates on some weird features.